# How can I modify a local HTML file in Perl?

Tags: html, perl, parsing

Is there a CPAN module or code snippet that I can use to modify local HTML files without using a regExp?

What I want to do :

1. Change the start tag ( example : `<div>`  to `<div id="newtag">` )
2. Add a tag before another ( example : `</head>` to `<script type="text/javascript"> ...</script></head>`
3. Remove tags
4. Read the content of a given tag. (<- ok this can be done with an XML / HTML parser.

Comment: There are quite a bit of answers to this on StackOverflow already, many with detailed examples. Always search first. :) Also, if you wonder if there is a CPAN module, go to [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) and look. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have HTML, and not XHTML, then you don't want to be using an XML parser.

[HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aParser) is the standard HTML parser for Perl.  Pretty much everything else is built on top of it.

[HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTokeParser) is an alternative interface to HTML::Parser.  It returns things on demand instead of passing everything to callbacks.

[HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) builds a DOM-like tree from the HTML, which you can then modify.

[HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) extends HTML::TreeBuilder with XPath support.

[HTML::Query](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aQuery) extends HTML::TreeBuilder with jQuery-like selectors.

[pQuery](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pQuery) is another module that brings more complete jQuery compatibility to HTML::TreeBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

**CPAN**

- [XML::XPATH](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-XPath-1.13/XPath.pm)
- [XML::Xerces](http://search.cpan.org/~jasons/XML-Xerces-1.7.0_0/DOMParse/DOMParse.pm#remove_%28%24node%29)

A simple CPAN search returns

- [XML Search](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=xml&mode=all)

**XPATH**

- [XPATH Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp)

It sounds like you are not familiar with XPath. Here is a quick tutorial to get you familiar. Its not Perl but it will explain the concepts.